# Custom Document-ID Provider with SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom, document-id

does anyone have a knowledge if this is possible to do for SharePoint Online?
[How to Create a Custom Document-ID Provider with SharePoint 2013](http://www.sharepointeurope.com/blog/2013/11/21/how-to-create-a-custom-document-id-provider-with-sharepoint-2013)

I did a solution (sandbox) and I managed to activate it in SPO but after trying to activate the feature I got the error and the correlation id which is pretty useless on SPO.

Has anyone succeeded with using the custom document id provider?

Comment: it Sems that it is a Core solution. This solution Type is not possible to deploy in spo. A sanboxed solution will not help here i think.

Comment: Any offical documentation about this ? I am also interested in solution for this.

Comment: @Sascha : If I am sending documents to a record centre library from more than one site collection. Is there a way to find out from where the record came in a record centre library?

Comment: I don't have enought experience in the RC-Lib. But I think that you could se this in the properties from the file entry. There must be set a Source URL or s.th. i think.

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement you need to write Server Object Model Code and this means that you need a farm solution which is, as you already mentioned, not possible in SharePoint Online. But you could use a [Remote event receivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx) which could handle this for you. You could create unique IDs through this remote event receivers.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/document-id-provider-sharepoint-add-in), there are 2 ways to set a document Id currently in SharePoint Online :

- Use remote event receivers (as already mentioned)
- Use a background process

In the second pattern, a background process checks documents in SharePoint to determine if they have a unique identifier set. If no unique identifier is found for a document, then the background process sets a unique identifier for the document. The background process makes CSOM or REST API calls to set unique identifiers for documents.